# paypal integration in php

Tags: php, paypal

First time I am starting to implement the paypal integration. Please tell me how to write code for a payment gateway(paypal) in php and it will be better if you will show a good demo from where I can get some ideas.

Comment: What have you tried so far? From memory I thought there were a few good examples that came with the SDK...

Comment: Hint: [PayPal Intergration Code Samples (incl. PHP)](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-code-samples)

Answer (score 0):

There are several sources on the net where you can find detailed information regarding paypal integration (with php). Here is one to be named:

- [Paypal](https://www.paypalobjects.com/IntegrationCenter/ic_sample-code.html)